# Key hash doesn't match while Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I try to use Facebook Sdk in my project,I got sha1 like this(I use Mac osX)

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I inserted sha1 in my project,but When i try to login with Facebook,have invalid key hash error .Here is my source

```
 public void getFacebookLogin()
{
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
            MainActivity.this,
            Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    System.out.println("Success");
                    accessToken= loginResult.getAccessToken();
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject json,
                                        GraphResponse response) {


                                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Success");
                                        try {
                                            facebookEmail = json.getString("email");
                                            Log.e("Token", "Token: " + accessToken.getToken());
                                            Log.e("UserID", "UserID: " + accessToken.getUserId());
                                            Log.e("facebookEmail", "facebookEmail: " + facebookEmail);
                                            if(!facebookEmail.isEmpty() && accessToken!=null && !accessToken.getToken().isEmpty())
                                                signInWithFacebook(facebookEmail,accessToken.getToken());
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,first_name,last_name,gender");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("TAG_CANCEL", "On cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Log.d("TAG_ERROR", error.toString());
                }
            });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?App is turn on in developer.facebook.com's panel.When I try to add sha1 in panel I have this alertDialog from Facebook

```
There was a problem verifying the package mypage on Google Play. Please 
check the package name and try again.
If your app isn't listed publicly on Google Play yet you can ignore 
this message.
```

I published my app in playstore but I have only beta testing version
How i can solve my problem?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure your debug keys are in ~/.android/debug.keystore. Also, if you published on Google Play, then you used a production key, not the debug key, so you need to get SHA1 for this key not the debug key

Comment: Thanks your attention .When I put this command in terminal,I got sha1 and inserted it in panel @Mohamed_AbdAllah

Comment: The command will produce output even if you entered wrong location or wrong credentials. You must make sure you provide correct location and credentials

Comment: Also, you need to do this command on the key you used to publish on Google Play (I assume you did not used debug key)

Comment: I also tried like this   keytool -exportcert -alias myalians -keystore ~/Users/myuser/Documents/AndroidProjects/myproject/myprojectkeytools| openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 and got sha1 .I'm using both sha1 in panel @ Mohamed_AbdAllah

Comment: Did you enter the correct key store password?

Comment: I put this command in terminal and it got sha1 @Mohamed_AbdAllah

Answer (score 0):

you are using the sha1 for debug key, regenerate the sha1 from the release key, and submit it on facebook dev website

Comment: I also tried to genarate sha1 with my project's keytools like this :   keytool -exportcert -alias myalians -keystore ~/Users/myuser/Documents/AndroidProjects/myproject/myproject‌​keytools| openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64  @AbuQauod